# How am i using wrongly the void expression?

Tags: c, function, void

I'm newbie in C and wanted to create a function that receives one integer `n` and one array `V`, and check if my array contains the values of `1` to `n`.

This is my actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void checkArray(int n, int* V);

void checkArray(int n, int* V){

    int remain = n;
    size_t length = sizeof V / sizeof V[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<length;j++){
            if(V[j] == remain){
                remain--;
            }
        }
    }
    if(remain == 0)
        printf("It's Latin");
        printf("Not Latin");
}

int main(){

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int V[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf(checkArray(n, V));

}
```

I'm getting the error at my printf, where it says invalid use of void expression.

Comment: Do you know what it means to have a function return void?

Comment: It means that it doesn't return anything right? or at least return null or something.

Comment: What output do you imagine `printf(checkArray(n, V))` would produce?

Comment: Exactly. In your code, the function returns nothing, and you're trying to output its return value. The function does the printing itself, so all you have to do is call it. You don't need to print the results again in `main()`.

Comment: `printf()` expects a `const char *` as the first argument. You can't have `void` as a parameter type.

Comment: @RyuujinWillyWillyLee It means it doesn't return anything; returning `NULL` means something different. What do you expect `printf(checkArray(n, V))` to mean when `checkArray` doesn't return anything?

Comment: Oh, ok, but how do I use the function then? I learned how to code in Java, but there i'm using objects.

Comment: Just do `checkArray(n, V);`. The function will print the results itself.

Comment: I only used printf as i typed how to use a function in C hahaha

Comment: Ok, thanks i'll try! xD

Comment: @RyuujinWillyWillyLee The `void` keyword works just like in Java; if a function returns `void` you can't use it as a parameter to another function, and you can just call functions without them being parameters to other functions.

Comment: You should take another look at your function too. If you don't want to always print "Not Latin" you need an else, and always using braces is a good habit to learn in my opinion. I've seen bugs caused by not using them but never by using them.

Comment: Ok, I'll use it, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Your `checkArray()` function returns nothing (which is what `void` means) and you are trying to print that 'nothing' which is obviously impossible. Your `checkArray()` function already prints the result so you don't need to print anything in `main()`.

It's seems though that you are missing `else` before `printf("Not Latin")` and your `length` variable is also incorrect. The `V` parameter of your `checkArray()` function is just a pointer (like a reference) to array and it doesn't hold any size information, you'll have to pass size separately to your function if you want to be able to traverse the array properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there are two mistakes in your program.
1. You didn't put "else" condition in function definition.
2. you already print something in your functions definitions so no need to use 'printf' in main() function.
you just call that function.
and put "return 0;" in last of the main function.

Answer (score 0):

To put together:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void checkArray(int n, int* V, size_t length);

void checkArray(int n, int* V, size_t length){
    int remain = n;

    for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<length;j++){
            if(V[j] == remain){
                remain--;
            }
        }
    }
    if(remain == 0){
        printf("It's Latin");
    else {
        printf("Not Latin");
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    size_t length;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    int V[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    length = sizeof(V) / sizeof(V[0]);

    checkArray(n, V, length);
    return 0;
}
```